# Хранение меняющихся данных в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт работает на WordPress. Необходимо разработать функционал, который позволил бы бронировать услугу. Со своей стороны я вижу это так: создаем раздел типа запись, в одной записи могут храниться несколько услуг. Предположим, что реализую это с помощью плагина acf, строка будет содержать название и количество. Механизм такой, что пользователь, заходя на сайт, тыкает по нужной плитке, отправляет заявку и ему в ответ прилетает, есть еще услуга или нет (возможно, сколько осталось еще напишет в ответ).

Вопрос в следующем: как мне хранить мне вот это количество услуг и как мне их менять? В принципе, это товар и количество, но товары объединены в группы в записи.

Или же здесь какой-то другой механизм нужен? Не могу допереть.

Answer (score 0):

Делать надо через создание [кастомного типа постов](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type). Один пост-одна услуга. Эти посты разнесены по своим [таксономиям](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy). Кстати, самая распространённая в мире система электронных магазинов WooCommerce работает по такому же принципу - кастомные посты типа product, один пост - один товар, им присвоены таксономии.

Comment: Геморно будет в данном случае как мне кажется. Необходимо таблицу с расписанием занятий выводить на страницу, предполагал что 1 запись - это одна неделя в записи с помощью плагина acf разобью по дням ну и в каждом дне есть несколько занятий. Для чистого вывода вроде бы все норм, но вдруг потребовалось чтобы можно было записываться на занятие и при этом ограниченное количество раз (соответственно занятия могут быть одинаковые но в разные дни). И мой план навернулся, не могу с логикой разобраться как теперь быть.

Comment: Вот потому план и навернулся. Должно быть - один кастомный пост - одно занятие с датой. Вывод недели - выборка по кастомным постам за неделю. Вывод дня - выборка за день. Кол-во записей на занятие - поле в занятии.

Comment: Вариант как мне кажется не подходит, в неделю порядка 30-70 различных занятий, 1 запись это одно занятие за определенное время то нужно и делать тогда все эти записи, но тут загвоздка что каждую неделю они могут быть в другое время и другая дата получается, следовательно по новой нужно все заполнять.

Comment: Все равно все по-новой заполнять. Возьмите уже какой-нибудь плагин расписаний и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Как раз ищу, что то подходящее, но так как первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь поэтому прорабатываю все варианты